User is not part of the schema for this Realm
Getting above exception while trying to access Realm database.
I tried various method which is suggested in stackoverflow. But nothing solves the problem. I have provided the details please help me resolve the issue. App gets crashed when trying to get User class.
build.gradle(Project:My_project)

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

        maven {
            url 'https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm/raw/master/maven-repo'
        }
    }
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

build.gradle(Module:app)
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android"
    id "com.google.gms.google-services"
    id "com.google.firebase.crashlytics"
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 34

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17' 
    }

    compileOptions {
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23
        compileSdkVersion 34
        targetSdkVersion 34
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 20190702
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:2.1.1'
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx:19.0.3")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:22.1.0")
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2'
    implementation "io.realm:realm-android-library:10.15.1"
    implementation 'com.github.yukuku:ambilwarna:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.2.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.uphyca:stetho_realm:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.HotBitmapGG:RingProgressBar:V1.2.2'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.13.0'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:24.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.Gavras:MultiLineRadioGroup:v1.0.0.6'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation project(':photoeditorsdk')
    implementation project(':videocompression')
}

settings.gradle
pluginManagement {

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()

        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven {
            url 'https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm/raw/master/maven-repo'
        }
    }
}

plugins {
    id "com.android.application" version "8.3.1" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.0" apply false
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.4.2" apply false
    id "com.google.firebase.crashlytics" version "2.9.9" apply false
}

include ':app', ':photoeditorsdk', ':videocompression'

User class
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose; 
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName; 
import io.realm.RealmObject; 
import io.realm.annotations.PrimaryKey;

public class User extends RealmObject { 
@PrimaryKey 
@SerializedName("userID")
 @Expose 
private long userId; 

public long getUserID() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserID(long userID) {
    this.userId = userID;
}
}

Application class onCreate
RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .name(Realm.DEFAULT_REALM_NAME)
                .schemaVersion(1)
                .migration(new RealmMigrations())
                .build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);

RealmMigration class
import io.realm.DynamicRealm;
import io.realm.RealmMigration;
import io.realm.RealmSchema;

public class RealmMigrations implements RealmMigration {


    @Override
    public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
        // DynamicRealm exposes an editable schema
        RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();
        /* Migrate to version 1:
        Added a new colum in Audit Table .*/

      if (oldVersion == 0) {
            schema.get("Audit")
                    .addField("savedAsDraft", boolean.class);

            oldVersion++;

        }
    }
}


Did you try class User extends Realm.Object instead of RealmObject? e.g. add a . in Realm.Object.?

Thanks Jay, Realm.Object is not getting for me.

I believe Realm.Object is the correct syntax. However, it appears your plan is to have Users in your app and in light of todays announcement of MongoDB abandoning all Realm SDK's, Authentication and terminating Sync services, it may be a mute point.

I made change accordingly you said, but this is the error I am getting Cannot resolve symbol 'Object'.

Hmm. Can you tag your question with your coding platform?

I am using Android studio Koala

ok. I fixed your question with the proper tags - hopefully someone can answer.
